# TypeError: getUserInfo is not a function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am using Jest for unit testing my code.

I have a file userinfo.js

```
const getuserdata = async function (req, res, next) {
    let userinfo = await getUserInfo();
    return userinfo;
}

const getUserInfo = async function (req, res, next) {
    const records = await database.query('select * from users');
    return records;
}
module.exports = {
  getuserdata,
  getUserInfo
}
```

I want to write test in jest
I created a file userinfo.test.js for testing.

code:

```
const { getuserdata, getUserInfo } = require('./userinfo');

describe('user data', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  test('user info', async () => {
    jest.mock('Path of file', () => ({ getUserInfo: jest.fn() }));
    getUserInfo.mockResolvedValue([{id: 1, name: "test", password: "123456"}]);
    const userdata = await getuserdata();
    expect(userdata).not.toBeUndefined();
  });
}
```

I want to test getuserdata but mock getUserInfo.
When I try to mock by above method it is giving me error that: TypeError: getUserInfo is not a function

but if I save the getUserInfo in different file then mocking is working properly. can you please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: How are you exporting them?

Comment: in userinfo.js  I am exporting  module.exports = {
  getuserdata,
  getUserInfo }

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some refactoring. We need to make sure `getUserInfo` method has the same reference, then you can add spy on it or replace it with a mocked object. You should **NOT** use `jest.mock` in the function scope. It should be used in the module scope. This scenario is more appropriate to use `jest.spyOn` to mock `getUserInfo` method and its returned value.

E.g.

`userinfo.js`:

```js
const database = require('./database');

const getuserdata = async function (req, res, next) {
  let userinfo = await exports.getUserInfo();
  return userinfo;
};

const getUserInfo = async function (req, res, next) {
  const records = await database.query('select * from users');
  return records;
};

exports.getuserdata = getuserdata;
exports.getUserInfo = getUserInfo;
```

`database.js`:

```js
const database = {
  query(sql) {
    console.log('real implementation');
  },
};

module.exports = database;
```

`userinfo.test.js`:

```sh
const userInfo = require('./userinfo');

describe('62539321', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const getUserInfoSpy = jest
      .spyOn(userInfo, 'getUserInfo')
      .mockResolvedValue([{ id: 1, name: 'test', password: '123456' }]);
    const userdata = await userInfo.getuserdata();
    expect(userdata).toEqual([{ id: 1, name: 'test', password: '123456' }]);
    getUserInfoSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  62539321
    ✓ should pass (7ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   71.43 |       50 |   33.33 |      75 |                   
 database.js |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 3                 
 userinfo.js |   72.73 |       50 |      50 |   77.78 | 9-10              
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.609s
```